Which healing spells heal undead?
I'm aware that some healing spells, such as:

Cure XYZ Wounds series,
Heal,

...do deal damage to undead creatures instead. There's plenty of other, interesting healing spells though, such as:

Purify Body,
Regenerate,
Reversion series,

...and many others that do not mention the positive/negative energy distinction within their spell description.
Does this mean only specific spells have local rules about harming undead instead or is there some kind of global rule I couldn't find that says all spells from Healing subschool harms undead instead?

Although for Pathfinder's antecedent, you may also be interested in this question.

Only healing spells that use positive energy harm undead
The Advanced Race Guide has a section about features of undead creatures. It says, among others


Undead are harmed by positive energy and healed by negative energy. An undead creature with the fast healing special quality still benefits from that quality.


The negative energy affiny monster trait also says:

The creature is alive but reacts to positive and negative energy as if it were undead— positive energy harms it, negative energy heals it.

So this seems to be a general rule. It does not say that all healing spells harm undead, but that positive energy harms undead. The healing subschool description merely says:

Healing: Certain divine conjurations heal creatures or even bring them back to life.

It does not say that all conjuration(healing) spells are based on positive energy. So there seems to be no genreal rule for that.
Example cases
Looking at an example spell like Purify Body, it says

You align the target’s chakras and soothe any unwanted imperfections found within its physical form, leaving its body pristine and without any pain or weakness.

This does not heal you because it instills positive energy, but because it aligns your chakras and soothe unwanted imperfections. Hence, the spell should be able to heal an undead.
(The description of chakras mentions that

According to esoteric traditions, the vital force of ki derives from the Positive Energy Plane and flows to initiates via the emanations of the sun. [...] Ki collects in seven mystical vortices within the body called chakras. [...] The chakras distribute this energy throughout the creature’s physical body, granting it animate force and giving order to its constituent molecules.

Even though it derives from the Positive Energy plane, Ki is not the same as positive energy, so I think formally this means it will not harm undead. I could see a GM rule that this is too close to positive energy to work in the case of this specific spell, though).
Regenerate won't work as it says:

It has no effect on nonliving creatures (including undead).


The last sentence of Regenerate reads:  "It has no effect on nonliving creatures (including undead)."

@KerrAvon2055 Oops I totally missed that. Fixed, thank you!
